# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'images'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from sklearn import datasets, svm, metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

digits = plt.imread('/Users/aarik/Downloads/number.png')

_, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=4, figsize=(10, 3))

for ax, image, label in zip(axes, digits.images, digits.target):
    ax.set_axis_off()
    ax.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation="nearest")
    ax.set_title("Training: %i" % label)
```

I get the error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'images'

Im trying to read a number from a image using sklearn example code.

Comment: You're getting this error, because `digits` is am image read as a numpy array and not whatever datatype you intend it to be. It therefore does not have the attribute `images`. If [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html) is your example code, then you are loading `digits` differently.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.